How do I pass a prop into an array exported from a class so that this array instantiates its child components with that prop for react?
Problem Statement
I have an array that's exported from another file. I need to pass in a prop to it from the parent class such that the exported array instantiates with the prop as a value.
Problem Steps:

I have a class in typescript that displays information onto a page based on a switch statement (displayStuff.tsx)
The information displayed lives in an array that's populated and exported from another class.
That array is populated with other react components.
The problem is that the components in the array now need a prop passed into them from the displayStuff.tsx in order to initialize. However, since this array is already exported into the parent class, passing in the props now will have no effect.
Further complicating things is that the value we need to pass as a prop into the exported function is defined in the parent class (displayStuff.tsx) using the useLoaderData() React hook (which I think I'm not understanding)

Example Code
This is how the array is defined:
MyArray.tsx:
    const componentArray = [
        <ComponentOne />
        <ComponentTwo />
        <ComponentThree />

    ];


export default componentArray;

This is the parent class that uses the array:
displayStuff.tsx :
import person from .../demo/for/stackoverflow/person.tsx;
import dataDTO from .../demo/for/stackoverflow/dataDTO.tsx;
import Mood from .../demo/for/stackoverflow/Mood.tsx;
import {componentArray, componentArray2, componentArray3} from .../demo/for/stackoverflow/componentArray.tsx;

class displayStuff {
 **{originalData, dataDTO} = userLoaderData() as originalData;** 
const originalData = dataDTO; // this is the object I want to pass in as a prop to the component defined in the array


// Method that uses a switch statement to evaluate the enums
evaluateState() {
    console.log(`Evaluating the state of ${this.name}:`);

    // Switch statement to evaluate Mood
    switch (this.mood) {
        case Mood.Happy:
            console.log("display Stuff");
    functionThatDisplaysStuffInArray(componentArray3);
            break;
        case Mood.Sad:
            console.log("display Stuff");
    functionThatDisplaysStuffInArray(componentArray2);
            break;
        case Mood.Angry:
            console.log("This is the condition where we need components intitalized with props");
    functionThatDisplaysStuffInArray(componentArray);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Mood: Unknown.");
    }

 }
}

What I've already tried:

I've importing dataDTO directly into the array, but that won't work because it's defined in the previous class with the UserLoaderData() react hook.

I've tried making MyArray.tsx into a class that looks like the others so that I can take instantiateMe as a prop, use it to define the array, and then exporting the array but I keep getting the error "Modifiers cannot appear here" when I try to export the array:
  import dataDTO from .../demo/for/stackoverflow/dataDTO.tsx;

  type MyArrayProps = {
  originalDataDTO = dataDTO
  }
   export default function MyArray

//error displays here
export const componentArray = [
    <ComponentOne
propWeNeed={originalDataDTO} />
       <ComponentTwo />
       <ComponentThree />

}



I feel like making MyArray.tsx into a class and importing the props is the right way to do it but I'm stuck on something stupid.

In displayStuff where are you trying to pass originalData (or dataDTO, it's confusing what is what here) to any actual React component? What does functionThatDisplaysStuffInArray do? Looks like it is passed an array of JSX elements... I'm guessing you want to pass originalData here so it can be passed along to whatever is actually rendered? Please [edit] to clarify the problem and provide a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

note: I am not sure about the **{originalData, dataDTO} = userLoaderData() as originalData;** syntax you have.
Your question is marked as "react-hooks", and I am also unsure about why you use classes in your code, but anyway.
React functional components are basically functions that accept props as their  argument. Your array defined as:
const componentArray = [
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo />
    <ComponentThree />
}

Actually contains instances (rendered) components/nodes, and after JSX compilation, that part in a nutshell transpiles to:
const componentArray = [
  ComponentOne(),
  ComponentTwo(),
  ComponentThree()
]

Which is not something you can pass props to. Instead, store your component functions directly in the array:
const componentArray = [
  ComponentOne,
  ComponentTwo,
  ComponentThree
]

This would allow you to render your list of components as:
return <div>
  {componentArray.map(component => component({propWeNeedToPass: someValue}))}
</div>


None of this answers the question, nor is any of it even correct.
For starters, you pass props into functional components all the time.
Your answer also loads props into all components instead of just one (which isn't what I asked).
The question is marked "react hook" because (as it says in the question) useDisplayLoader (a react hook) is used to define the variable in the parent class.
